# How do I register IDbConnectionFactory using Castle Windsor

Tags: servicestack, castle-windsor, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using a Windsor adapter with service stack and wondering how to register an IDbConnection factory into my installer e.g. in AppHostBase this is

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider));
```

If I do this inside a Windsor installer , the compiler complains "non generic method cannot be used with type arguments"

What mods do I need to make this registration part of the windsor installer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the equivalent in Castle Windsor:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IDbConnectionFactory>()
    .Instance(
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider)));
```